# Examples of adjoint order morphisms

Tags: order-theory

Given posets $(X, \leq)$, and $(Y, \leq)$, an *order morphism* is a map $f : X \to Y$ such that $x \leq y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$.

Given two order morphism $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$, we say that $f$ is a *left adjoint* of $g$ (or that $g$ is a *right adjoint* of $f$) if for all $x \in X, y \in Y$ we have
$$
x \leq g(y) \Leftrightarrow f(x) \leq y
$$
in which case we also call $(f, g)$ an adjoint pair.

Classical examples are:

1. For an extension of fields $F \subseteq K$, let $\mathcal{F}$ be the poset of intermediate fields (ordered by inclusion) and $\mathcal{G}$ the poset of subgroups of the Galois group Gal$(K/F)$, ordered by inclusion. Then
   $$
   f: \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{F}^{op} : H \mapsto \text{Fix}(H) \\
   g: \mathcal{F}^{op} \to \mathcal{G} : L \mapsto \text{Gal}(K/L)
   $$
   forms an adjoint pair.
2. Let $(X, \leq)$ be a poset and for $Y \subseteq X$ define ub$(Y) = \lbrace x \in X \vert \forall y \in Y: y \leq x \rbrace$, similarly define lb$(Y) = \lbrace x \in X \vert \forall y \in Y: x \leq y \rbrace$. Letting $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be the power set of $X$, ordered by inclusion, then
   $$
   \text{ub} : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(X)^{op} : Y \mapsto \text{ub}Y \\
   \text{lb} : \mathcal{P}(X)^{op} \to \mathcal{P}(X) : Y \mapsto \text{lb}Y
   $$
   forms an adjoint pair.
3. For a field $k$ and the $n$-dimensional affine space $\mathbb{A}^{n}(k)$, the maps
   $$
   V : \mathcal{P}(k[X_1, ..., X_n]) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{A}^{n}(k))^{op} : I \mapsto \lbrace x \in \mathbb{A}^{n}(k) \vert \forall f \in I : f(x) = 0 \rbrace \\
   I : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{A}^{n}(k))^{op} \to \mathcal{P}(k[X_1, ..., X_n]) : V \mapsto \lbrace f \in k[X_1, ..., X_n] \vert \forall x \in V : f(x) = 0 \rbrace
   $$
   form an adjoint pair.

All these examples, however, rely on arbitrarily considering the opposite relation on one of the two posets (for a poset $(X, \leq)$, the poset $(X^{op}, \leq^{op})$ is the set $X$ with order $x \leq^{op} y \Leftrightarrow y \leq x$). In fact, all maps considered 'reverse' the natural order and these structures are also known als general *Galois connections*; more examples are given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98839/examples-of-galois-connections). Are there interesting examples of adjoint pairs which respect the *natural* order on both sets? I'm looking for adjoint pairs of posets, not of categories.

Comment: The image mapping associated with a mapping is left-adjoint to the preimage mapping, rounding up is left-adjoint to forgetting that a real number is actually an integer, linear hull is left adjoint to forgetting everything about a subvectorspace except its elements, similarly for other universal algebras. There are many examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Examples of Galois connections?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98839/examples-of-galois-connections)

Comment: Note, that order adjunctions are also known as Galois connections.